Numpy and Sympy doing different things
I have constructed two numpy arrays (matrices). I have then converted the arrays to sympy matrices. One of the matrices is the inverse of the other. When I multiply the sympy matrices togheter I get something that is not the unit matrix. Why do I not get the unit matrix back? I get it back if I multiply the numpy matrices.
Edit:
This is the piece of code:
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
e1 = 1                
e2 = 1
e3 = 1
e4 = 1
t = 1                
lambda_so = 10**(-3)  

ny = 1/(2+(np.pi/2)**2)
e1matrix = e1*np.eye(2)
e2matrix = e2*np.eye(2)
e3matrix = e3*np.eye(2)
e4matrix = e4*np.eye(2)
tmatrix = t*np.eye(2)
v1matrix = ny*lambda_so*np.array([[2,np.pi*1j],[-np.pi*1j,-2]])
v2matrix = ny*lambda_so*np.array([[2,-np.pi],[-np.pi,-2]])

H = np.block([[e1matrix,tmatrix,v1matrix,np.zeros((2,2))], 
              [tmatrix,e2matrix,tmatrix,v2matrix], 
              [v1matrix.conj().T,tmatrix,e3matrix,tmatrix],
              [np.zeros((2,2)),v2matrix.conj().T,tmatrix,e4matrix]])


eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(H)
eigenvectors_on = orth(eigenvectors)
                          
#First constructed matrix
U = eigenvectors_on                                                                                   
#Second constructed matrix
U_H = np.linalg.inv(U)

#Converting the two matrices to sympy matrices
U_sy = sp.Matrix(U)
U_H_sy = sp.Matrix(U_H)

print(f'Matrix multiplication between the two numpy matrices: {np.around(U@U_H,0)} gives back the unit matrix')
print(f'Matrix multiplication between the two sympy matrices: {U_sy*U_H_sy} gives back a matrix where the elementwise multiplication have not been carried out. If one do the multiplication the first element the sum is not 1 or close to it as one would expect.')


Try to create an MRE and show it as properly formatted text in the question.

I suppose it has something to do with how floating point numbers work but without an example we can only guess

Well, sympy tries to do exact symbolic calculations. As such, e.g. np.pi is just an approximation of sp.pi. In general, calling sp.Matrix(U_H) on a numpy matrix of floats is a very bad use case for sympy. Also note that inverting a matrix in a numerical way quickly leads to accuracy problems (not for 2x2 matrices, but I suppose your envisioned use case is more complicated).  And inverting a matrix in a symbolic way, quickly leads to extremely complicated expressions.  What exactly do you want to obtain?

Hi, the code has an error! The function orth in your code is not defined.
